# Insomnia returns 404 on POST to Keycloak, but Postman does not

Tags: post, postman, keycloak, insomnia

When trying to run a POST request to my Keycloak container (using Docker) in Insomnia, I am greeted with a 404 error. Running the same command with the same parameters in Postman however returns the site properly. They use the same URL, Forms and Headers, but Insomnia is not communicating with Keycloak whilst Postman is.

URL `http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

HEADER `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

The request options are functioning correctly as it works as intended in Postman and returns a token, but Insomnia does not communicate with Keycloak at all (verified by Keycloak logs as there is no entry). I need to use Insomnia over Keycloak for file purposes. Is there anything that could potentially be preventing Insomnia from communicating with Keycloak when Postman properly accesses it?

Thanks in advance.